# jquery remove with backbone.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a jquery to add li to existing ul by clicking a button and remove one by one by clicking other button. Creation is working  but deletion is not working. I used append and remove to add and delete li.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('body'), // el attaches to existing element 
        events: {
            'click button#add': 'addItem',
            'click button#remove': 'removeItem'
        },
        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem','removeItem'); 
            this.counter = 0; // total number of items added thus far
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>Add list item</button>");
            $(this.el).append("<button id='remove'>Remove list item</button>");
            $(this.el).append("<ul></ul>");
        }, 
        addItem: function(){
            this.counter++;
            $('ul', this.el).append("<li>hello world"+this.counter+"</li>");
        },
        removeItem: function(){
            alert(this.counter);
            $('li',this.el).remove("<li>hello world"+this.counter+"</li>");
        }
    });
    var listView = new ListView(); 
});
```

Comment: What about `this.counter--` when removing an item?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to remove last element on click of remove, if that is the case. you can change remove item to

```
addItem: function(){
    this.counter++;
    $('ul', this.el).append("<li class='count-"+this.counter+"'>hello world"+this.counter+"</li>");
},
removeItem: function(){
    $('li.counter-'+this.counter+,this.el).remove()
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer.. but how can i remove specific li using count?

Comment: if you want that to be removed by count, add a class to each li while create, something like  "count-3", then change to `$('li.count-3',this.el).remove()`, updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can either call `remove()` on an element to remove itself, or give it an valid selector to remove some other elements. So you can try either

```
$('li:contains("hello world' + this.counter+ '")', this.el).remove()
```

or

```
$('ul', this.el).remove('li:contains("hello world' + this.counter+ '")')
```

Here I'm using the `:contains` selector. In your scenario you can also use the `:last-child` selector which simplifies it as:

```
$('li:last-child', this.el).remove()
```

or

```
$('ul', this.el).remove('li:last-child')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cant't remove the item by passing it's whole html to the remove method, you need to use a selector, so either an id, class, type or whatever.

```
removeItem: function(e){
  $('ul',this.el).remove('li:nth-child('+counter+')');
}
```

This would remove one li from the ul depending on your counter. If you want to remove one special li you will need to change the setup, because how could the button know which li to remove on click.

You can make the li itself the remove button for example:

```
events: {
 'click li': 'removeLi'
}
```

and as remove function:

```
removeLi: function(e){
  $(e.target).remove();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or, sticking to your `counter` thingy:

```
    removeItem: function(){
        alert(this.counter);

        this.$('li').eq(this.counter-1).remove();
        this.counter--;
    }
```

[jQuery.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

Your remove function is buggy.
You can use the 'nth-child(nth)' css selector for removing the item...

```
removeItem: function(){
  $('ul ' + 'li:nth-child('+this.counter+')',this.el).remove()            
  this.counter--;
}
```